# Is there a relationship between the zeta function of a Laplacian and the Selberg Zeta Function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let us define the zeta function of an elliptic differential operator $H$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ like so:
 \begin{aligned}
    \zeta_H(s) 
:= 
    tr( H^{-s} )
    \\
    :=
    \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{(\lambda_n)^s}
  \end{aligned}
 Then, for a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ with Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta$, the Minakshisundaram–Pleijel zeta function is given by $\zeta_\Delta(s)$.

The Selberg Zeta Function of a Riemannian surface has a lot more setup, although a definition can be found in Definition 4.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/dg-ga/9407012.pdf).

As I study the Minakshisundaram–Pleijel zeta function, I see that it has a lot in common with the Selberg Zeta Function, in terms of analogous objects in algebraic geometry (both have intimate connections to Artin L-functions). My question - is there anything connecting one of these functions to another? I've seen mentioned that the Selberg Zeta Function can be considered a zeta function of a twisted Dirac operator, which would make both special cases of the zeta function defined above, but that's not all that direct of a connection.

Are there any rigorous connections between these two functions?

Comment: You need $\zeta_\Delta$ to define the regularized determinant. The latter can be used to express the Selberg zeta function as you see [https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104159171].

Comment: @Corbennick That's an incredibly helpful paper! I can't tell what they mean by $\Delta_n$ (as in corollary 1) - is that simply the Laplacian? If not, can that corollary be extended to be the determinant of the laplacian?

Comment: That's the spinor Laplacian. For n=0 it's the usual, I guess.

Comment: @Corbennick If you expand that into an answer, I’ll check it! Thank you!

Comment: @TreFox: What "intimate connections" do the Minakshisundaram-Pleijel and Selberg $\zeta$ functions have with Artin L-functions? The former two are deeply Riemannian in nature, while the latter are deeply arithmetic (and have significantly more nice properties).

Comment: @AlexM. The Selberg Zeta Function of an operator is expressible as a Euler product of characteristic polynomials of the determinants of the monodromies of the flat connection corresponding to the given group representation. If one interprets a Frobenius map as an element of the arithmetic fundamental group of an arithmetic curve and a Galois representation as a flat connection, the definitions of an Artin L-function and the Selberg Zeta function are analogous.

Comment: @AlexM. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179583/artin-l-function-and-zeta-function-of-twisted-dirac-operator?rq=1 for a better description of what I'm talking about. It may not be rigorous, but they are certainly connected.